# How force the Client Bacula execute over a specific interface?

Tags: linux, networking, oracle-linux

my first question here.

I have the following backup below:

**Bacula 5.2**  - Ubuntu Server 12

> - 192.168.1.113

**Oracle database** - Oracle Linux 5.7

> - 192.168.1.24 - eth0 - Used for ERP production.
> - 192.168.1.49 - eth1 - for backups

In bacula-dir put it to connect to the Oracle Server client by IP 192.168.1.49 as follows:

```
Client {
   Name = imdban1-fd
   Address = 192.168.1.49
   FDPort = 9102
   Catalog = MyCatalog
  }
```

However, I monitoring via Nagios the Oracle server network cards are showing that the traffic is going over eth0 card (192.168.1.24)

Link interface:
[Image Nagios network Card](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ffnlsbelbqoudtw/rede.png)

I execute the netstat command on Oracle server and I found this:

```
bacula-fd 22543        0    3u  IPv4 162890832       TCP 192.168.1.49:9102 (LISTEN)
bacula-fd 22543        0    5u  IPv4 163037153       TCP 192.168.1.24:39565->192.168.1.113:9103 (ESTABLISHED)
```

I want the backup run through IP 192.168.1.49, not 1.24

I can see the service is running through 1.49, but the transfer is going through 1.24

What I can do on this case?

EDIT: I found this command:

> ip route add -host 192.168.1.113 via 192.168.1.1 src 192.168.1.49 dev eth1

I will try in a safe period....

Comment: You need to route the traffic to 192.168.1.49 over a specific interface.  The specific command to use depends on which particular networking utilities package is installed on your OEL 5.7 platform.

Comment: EDIT: I found this command:

**ip route add -host 192.168.1.113 via 192.168.1.1 src 192.168.1.49 dev eth1**

I will try in a safe period....

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution..

I execute this command:

```
route add -host 192.168.1.113 dev eth1
```

Now the backup copies are through the IP 1.49. ;)